# How to solve simultaneity bias in groovy

Tags: groovy

What is the best way of solving the simultaneity bias in groovy?

I have a issue with a queue. I select all queue with state wait and 
update the state to running. Most of the time it goes okay, but sometimes by error state running get loaded from another thread.

I know from study time, I get illustrated to a way to solve through java. But I can't remember how.

Below should illustrate the problem.

Thread one:

```
List<Queue> elements = Queue.findAll { state = wait }

sleep(1000)  //Illustration of a delay

elements.each {
   it.state = running
   it.save()
}
```

Thread two (starts at same time as thread one):

```
List<Queue> elements = Queue.findAll { state = wait } //The error occur here, as thread one already begin executing same elements.


//Problem should be solved somehow here.
elements.each {
   it.state = running
   it.save()
}
```

Thread two select same element as Thread one. But thread two should not go further with the element, as Thread one is the owner now.

Comment: Can you come up with a simple example of your problem that we can run?

Comment: tim yates it is a little hard, has the problem occur very rarely.

Comment: Not going to be easy to answer if we don't know what you're doing

Comment: Okay I tried to illustrate through some pseudo code. I seen a standard in java once through study, but I don't remember how exactly.

Comment: `Queue` -  is it [java Queue](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Queue.html) ?

Comment: no it is not java. My illustration was just simpler to illustrate with queue.